# How can I get my materials to look like the materials in this photo?

Tags: materials, shaders

This artist that I follow uses Cinema 4D and creates some unique models but the thing I particularly like is the way the materials of his models look. I know he uses a different program than blender but it must be possible to get blender materials to look like his right?

This is the link to his twitter: https://twitter.com/creativecloud/status/1256438275696398336/photo/3

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Answer (score 2):

I looks a bit like a gum material, maybe try to increase the *Roughness* (here 0.9) so that you don't have too much reflection, and give it a bit of *Subsurface* (here 0.4) so that it is not too contrasted:

[image]

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind that the lighting is a very big part of the final look of the materials. It seems like you'd want a bright, maybe vaguely yellowish, fairly diffuse lighting setup or hdri to get results like the one in the photo.